# How can I view the amount of recoil on a gun without using it in CoD: Advanced Warfare?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

The title says it all, I just was wondering if there was some way to actually see the recoil of a gun as a "number".

Comment: I don't believe so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people report that Advanced Warfare gun stats have not been decrypted yet. Usually with Call of Duty, modders find ways to decrypt those files and publish the numbers, which allows for the creation of "gun charts". The developpers seem to have hidden the numbers and the actual numbers cannot be found on the internet. However, you can take a look at tests ran by people from the community, who sometimes give estimates.

Moreover, I think (please verifiy it, do not take my word) that the [accuracy](http://youtu.be/aCUdAjFpk1g?t=3m20s) stat which can be seen on the weapon official stats ingame affects recoil.

Source : [Drift0r](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCk8cNb10L5rmV9xB13ADCWA) (Youtuber) and others